# Facing issue with South and Django "There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database."

Tags: django, django-south

I am try to develop one project in Python and Django using South for database migration.

I am very new to south and currently facing one problem when try to run any command syncdb or runserver that is :

"There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS."

I am using following versions 
Django==1.4.2,

South==0.7.6,

psycopg2==2.4.5

Postgres 9.2.2

Python==2.7.1 for the configuration.

I am trying to configure this project on mac machine 10.7.5

Database Settings info:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }

}

SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2',
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
AnshJ

Comment: please show us your DATABASES variable in settings.py

Comment: I don't think setting the database adapter for South is necessary.

Comment: Even if i remove that "SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS" settings file still getting the same error.

Comment: This is duplicate of [#29478400](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478400/there-is-no-south-database-module-south-db-postgresql-psycopg2-for-your-databa/29489596#29489596).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very sill mistake by me, I have 2 different version of south in my project path and one of south didn't have postgresql_psycopg2.py file under db folder and which actually get loaded.

Thanks,

Regards,
AnshJ