# no South database module 'south.db.sqlite3'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
There is no South database module 'south.db.sqlite3'
```

This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': 'south.db.sqlite3'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql\_psycopg2' for your database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478400/there-is-no-south-database-module-south-db-postgresql-psycopg2-for-your-databa)

Comment: what version of django are u using ?, because there are some changes happened from django 1.7 in migrations and we need to make some changes to remove south dependency

Comment: I'm using django 1.8. Django doesn't need south anymore to update models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to address this by specifically installing Django 1.6 with `pip install django==1.6`.

You may also have luck if you add

```
SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': 'south.db.sqlite3'
}
```

If that don't work may be your answer can be here : 
http://answerhub.com/qa/questions/28185/how-do-i-get-syncdb-to-work-im-getting-there-is-no.html

Comment: Sorry this post is just wrong. In fact the problem is your django version. If you use south you need Django 1.6 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478400/there-is-no-south-database-module-south-db-postgresql-psycopg2-for-your-databa